# PHP resizing PNG images generate black background

Tags: php, image

This is the part of the code I use to display or resize and display with Cache headers. It works fine for JPG images. But PNG images get added with black background. This type of questions are available in SO and Google but almost the solutions accepted or suggested are same: `imagealphablending` - FALSE and `imagesavealpha` - TRUE. But in my case, nothing works. What would be the problem?

```
$image_information=getimagesize($img);
if($image_information['mime']=='image/gif')
{
    $img=imagecreatefromgif($img);
    $type="gif";
    $image_header="image/gif";
}
elseif($image_information['mime']=='image/png')
{
    $img=imagecreatefrompng($img);
    $type="png";
    $image_header="image/png";
}
else
{
    $img=imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
    $type="jpg";
    $image_header="image/jpeg";
}

$width=imagesx($img);
$height=imagesy($img);

if((isset($w))&(!isset($h))) // If Width or Height is posted, calculate the aspect dimensions
{
    $h=($height/$width*$w);
}

if((isset($h))&(!isset($w)))
{
    $w=(($h*$width)/$height);
}

if(!isset($w))
{
    $w=$width;
}

if(!isset($h))
{
    $h=$height;
}


$new_image=imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

if($type=="gif")
{
    $background=imagecolorallocate($new_image, 0, 0, 0);
    // removing the black from the placeholder
    imagecolortransparent($new_image, $background); 
}
elseif($type=="png")
{
    imagealphablending($new_image, FALSE);
        imagesavealpha($new_image, TRUE);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
        imagefilledrectangle($new_image, 0, 0, $w, $h, $transparent);
}

imagecopyresampled($new_image,$img,0,0,0,0,$w,$h,$width,$height);
$seconds_to_cache = 864000; // Add cache headers
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $seconds_to_cache) . " GMT";
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control:max-age=$seconds_to_cache, must-revalidate");
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", $lastModified)." GMT");


header('Content-Type: $image_header');
if($type="jpg")
imagejpeg($new_image, NULL, 75);
elseif($type=="png")
imagepng($new_image, NULL, 75);
elseif($type=="gif")
imagegif($new_image, NULL);
imagedestroy($new_image);
```

**Edit**: I saved the image to my system, tried opening in,

1. Picasa Photo Viewer - Image opens with Black BG.
2. Ms Paint - Image opens with Black BG.
3. Photoshop CS6 - Error message pops out: Could not open because of Program error.

Comment: Is this usefull? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587972/php-script-to-resize-transparent-png-images

Comment: To clarify, is the problem with *saving* the image through PHP or *displaying* the image on the webpage through PHP?

Comment: Displaying the images with PHP. When needed in multiple sizes, I use the following stricture, "images/image-name.extension/int/int" -> extension will be jpg or png or gif and first int will be width in numbers and second will be height in numbers. Wither or both the int values can be omitted.

Comment: @Timvp: Quite good, now using it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the alpha channel from your original image.

add

`imagealphablending($img, true);`

right above the following code

`$width=imagesx($img);
$height=imagesy($img);`

EDIT:

and then try this

```
$transparent = imagecolortransparent($new_image, imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 255, 255, 255, 127));
imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $transparent);
```

instead of your transparent code with filled rectangle

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a well coded class to do image manipulation. [Verot.net's php class for image upload](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm?PHPSESSID=d51e9cbd81f0c904f0a838992988e1f7) offers, on top of the upload manipulation, all sorts of image manipulation functionalities in a DRY, well structured API. In the end, your code will be much more portable and futureproof.

Comment: Thank you pixeline, but I just wanted to know the reason for my code does not work. I saw similar scripts available in the Internet already.

Comment: OK. I would then look at what image manipulation library your specific server configuration is using. Is it GD? GD2? ImageMagick? From my experience, ImageMagick is the best and most versatile. See which is installed (phpinfo() will give you that). Otherwise, you're shooting in the dark.